# I need to try the following code inside the ngOnInit function

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, subscribe

In the following code sample I present the ngOnInit method following a call to the service to find out which row was selected.

What I need is to test the call inside the subcribe

this is the component code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData();
    this.loadRoles();
    // Se suscribe a los cambios que ocurran al cambiar de row en el datatable usuario
    this.subscriptions.push(this.selectRowServices.selectRow$.subscribe( (row: any) => {
      this.usuarioSelect = row;
      Iif ( this.usuarioSelect != null ) {
        this.loadUsuarioRol();
      }
    }));
  }
```

I would like to reach the internal part of the following code to test it, after the subcribe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAZZG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the test using jasmine

```
it('usuario select is not null', () => {
spyOn(component, 'loadUsuarioRol');
component.ngOnInit();
component.selectRowServices.selectRow$.next({});
expect(component.loadUsuarioRol).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much for your help. The service, being declared as private in the component, cannot be called in the way specified by you above, but I did it by importing with a test Inject